# is it possible to run single application in both android and iphone

Tags: iphone, android, cross-platform

Is it possible to develop a single application that is able to run in both android and iphone.If can how can i done post some link. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure html/javascript should work, otherwise you might be able to build something using monotouch/monodroid

*edit
Stumbled on another way of doing it: http://www.xmlvm.org/android/

Answer (score 0):

or any other cross-platform framework with support for both platforms

check out this : [Technology to write iPhone, BlackBerry and Android phone at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821085/technology-to-write-iphone-blackberry-and-android-phone-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Mo'Minis](http://www.mominis.com/).