# Is there any common language to develop a same application for iphone, blackberry, windows mobile and android?

Tags: iphone, android, windows-mobile, blackberry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Technology to write iPhone, BlackBerry and Android phone at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821085/technology-to-write-iphone-blackberry-and-android-phone-at-the-same-time)

Is there any common language to develop a same application for iphone, blackberry, windows mobile and android?

Answer (score 3):

Writing HTML 5 applications is your best bet. X-plat only works well for game development. All these platforms have different UI constructs that do not map directly to other platforms.

You are better off writing web services to do the heavy lifting and writing thin UIs using the native SDKs so they match the platform.

Answer (score 2):

You could try PhoneGap ([www.phonegap.com](http://www.phonegap.com/))...

> PhoneGap is an open source development framework for building cross-platform mobile apps. Build apps in HTML and JavaScript and still take advantage of core features in iPhone/iTouch, iPad, Google Android, Palm, Symbian and Blackberry SDKs.

The language in question is javascript :)

Answer (score 2):

No. For those 3 environments you have a mix of Java, Objective C and .NET framework languages (VB,C#,C++), all which have very different requirements to run as well as to write. As suggested, PhoneGap can be of some use in this area, but you will only be able to write web based applications to work in various mobile environments.