# Is there an augmented reality framework that works on iPhone, Android, and Windows Phone 7?

Tags: iphone, android, windows-phone-7, augmented-reality

I want to develop an application which runs on iPhone / Android / Windows Phone 7 smartphones and is able to recognize a marker and place augmented reality content on it.

Is there any common framework which I could use for that task?

Comment: You will find answers on this question here: [is-there-a-multiplatform-framework-for-developing-iphone-android-applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953/is-there-a-multiplatform-framework-for-developing-iphone-android-applications) **Edit** You may also like this one: [technology-to-write-iphone-blackberry-and-android-phone-at-the-same-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821085/technology-to-write-iphone-blackberry-and-android-phone-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the closest you'll get:
http://nyatla.jp/nyartoolkit/wiki/index.php?FrontPage.en

Comment: i have heard of that, do you know how much the commercial licence would be?

Comment: No, you would have to contact them if you can't use the GPL license.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Android or iPhone, but Kevin Marshall has done some [proof-of-concept work on Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/2010/12/23/wp7-camera-access-flashlight-augmented-reality-and-barcode-scanning/). You should keep in mind though, that augmented reality on WP7 requires access to camera APIs that are not publicly available and as such any AR application on WP7 would not be available officially through the Marketplace. Device manfacturers (such as LG) have access to these APIs, which is how some AR applications already exist for WP7.

Comment: this sucks ... why did they do that? but thanks for the tip, i didnt know that.

Answer (score 1):

As Derek and Stefan point out, it appears that there are ports of the [ARToolKit](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/) augmented reality framework for all three platforms.

On iPhone, you can see this in the [VRToolkit sample application](http://www.benjaminloulier.com/posts/5-virtual-reality-on-iphone-code-inside) by Benjamin Loulier, which leverages the enhanced [ARToolKitPlus library](http://studierstube.icg.tu-graz.ac.at/handheld_ar/artoolkitplus.php).

For Android, it looks like NyARToolkit is available, with [this sample application](http://nyatla.jp/nyartoolkit/wiki/index.php?NyARToolkit%20for%20Android.en) (as pointed out by Stefan).

Finally, it looks like [SLARToolKit](http://slartoolkit.codeplex.com/) is used in the Windows Phone 7 sample application [here](http://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/2010/12/23/wp7-camera-access-flashlight-augmented-reality-and-barcode-scanning/) (as pointed out by Derek).

Be aware that this toolkit and its derivatives are licensed under the GPL:

> IMPORTANT NOTICE REGARDING YOUR RIGHT
>   TO USE ARTOOLKIT:
>
> ARToolKit is made available freely for
>   non-commercial use under the GNU
>   General Public License. Commercial
>   licenses to a professional
>   implementation of ARToolKit are
>   available for users for whom the GPL
>   is not suitable, or who require a
>   higher level of support, or who
>   require customization or other
>   specialist modifictions. Commercial
>   licenses are administered by
>   ARToolworks, Inc., Seattle, WA, USA.

I've seen people violating this license in their applications and derivative frameworks, so it's something to be aware of.

Comment: it will be a commercial app, so i would need a different licence. i think i read somewhere that artoolkit has a commercial licence around 900$/year. but im not quite sure.

Comment: @chris - Yes, the GPL is a hindrance to wide usage of this library.  In fact, a couple of other developers and I were talking about building a BSD alternative to the framework, targeted to iOS.  We still might do this, given the interest by others.  However, this would not work on Android or Windows Phone 7.

Comment: yes you are right. i really dont like gpl either. why not publish it with MIT licence, so nobody is forced to make his hard work public. in my understanding that is the normal way of "evolution", you take some idea and make it a little better without any limitations. but this forces you literally to start all over again with every problem.it would be nice if someone would develop such a framework, not with marker but with pictures. some functionality like "junaio glue" would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [Layar](http://layar.com)?

AFAIK they do not support WP7 but I guess it's a matter of time.

Comment: yes i did, but is layar not only for placing objects without any marker?

Comment: i did , seems they dont support this yet. i found "junaio glue" a nice alternative.