# Any good API for Augmented Reality in iphone

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality

I  am working on the iPhone  application in which I  need to implement Augmented  Reality functionality. But I am not aware of any Augmented  Reality API.

Please give me suggestions for any free/non-commercial Augmented  Reality API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Augmented Reality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921895/augmented-reality)

Comment: See also [Is there an augmented reality framework that works on iPhone, Android, and Windows Phone 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691885/is-there-an-augmented-reality-framework-that-works-on-iphone-android-and-window)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Augmented reality on iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716201/augmented-reality-on-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Get http://www.iphonear.org/ from github and do something like this from your UIViewController:

```
ARGeoViewController *arController = [[ARGeoViewController alloc] init];
arController.debugMode = YES;
arController.delegate = self;
arController.scaleViewsBasedOnDistance = YES;
arController.minimumScaleFactor = .5;
arController.rotateViewsBasedOnPerspective = YES;

NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CLLocation *tempLocation;
ARGeoCoordinate *tempCoordinate;
tempLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:40.756054 longitude:-73.986951];
tempCoordinate = [ARGeoCoordinate coordinateWithLocation:tempLocation];
tempCoordinate.title = @"New York City";
[locations addObject:tempCoordinate];
[tempLocation release];
[arController addCoordinates:locations];
[locations release];

[arController startListening];
[self presentModalViewController:arController animated:YES];
```

If you want to understand the code from arkit, it may help to check the talk from Jonathan Saggau at iDev|360: http://www.jonathansaggau.com/blog/2010/10/iphone_ipad_devcon_sample_code.html

Answer (score 0):

Qualcomm has some interesting items - there was even a competition recently for companies to showcase how their product could be used - [more on their website](http://developer.qualcomm.com/dev/augmented-reality)

Comment: That SDK appears to be for Android, not iPhone.

Comment: You're right - My mistake. I'll leave this response up in case anyone is interested in it though.

Answer (score 0):

Metaio SDK is compatible for android and iPhone. Download is free, but with a watermark. [This link](http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/getting-started/) also brings you to all the tutorials and demo code.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In 2016, Apple released a framework called ARKit which can be leveraged for AR application development. ARKit was introduced along with iOS 11. More details on the ARKIT and the usage of the API's can be obtained from the below link.
https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/arkit/