# Best platform for programming to IPad and new Windows and Android Pads

Tags: android, windows, ipad

would like to build an app that can run on any of the new PAD's hitting market.
I don't want to limit our users to a specific OS.

What is the best solution to allow all these pads to use our app.

The app needs to be able to run offline.

Thanks!

Comment: You're being a bit vague there. Try researching into cross-platform handheld device development. There are things for iphone/android dev like phonegap but if you choose to use those there will always be restrictions. I agree with @xil3; try writing a web application (if you can cache the pages or load them locally) if it _must_ work on all platforms.

Comment: No real point to diving too deep into the details of what the app would do.  I was just more concerned with if there was anything out there that would allow this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a web application and use HTML5 for off-line caching.

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html

Alternatively, you could try and use Titanium Mobile.

http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/

Answer (score 1):

You should also spend some time reading this discussions:

- [is-there-a-multiplatform-framework-for-developing-iphone-android-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953/is-there-a-multiplatform-framework-for-developing-iphone-android-applications)
- [technology-to-write-iphone-blackberry-and-android-phone-at-the-same-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821085/technology-to-write-iphone-blackberry-and-android-phone-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/), it will let you write all your logic in C# over all the main mobile platforms.   However you still need custom UI code for each platform, but as least it will all be in C#.

(Better then having to use C#, Java **and** Objective C)

Comment: It doesn't say anything about it working on Android - seems to be just for the iPhone/iPad/iPod

Comment: This might be a good option for us since all of our devs are familiar with c#.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Adobe Air that could works in most of Mobile/Tablet operating system [Iphone](http://www.flashmobileblog.com/2010/04/01/adobe-air-packager-for-iphone-os-demos/),[Android](http://www.adobe.com/newsletters/edge/august2010/articles/article1/index.html) and [Windows 7](http://blogs.adobe.com/air/2009/10/adobe_air_15_supports_windows.html). but im not sure if Apple will approve your App if you plan to released to the App market.

Another way to think about it is to create an HTML resources and then integrated in away seems native to the system its more work but you will have a higher chance to get approved from apple and the app look more integrated with the OS .

Answer (score 0):

The obvious -- and currently free -- answer is to use Adobe FlashBuilder to develop iOS apps.  There is an iPhone and iPad emulator included.  This does not use xcode, but you get most of the features to work with, and you can also develop Android apps from the same set of code.  Further, with minor modifications for mouse usage, you can also have the apps run on any desktop as an Air app.

Adobe's website has [detailed directions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/index.html) for how to create iOS apps on Windows with Adobe Air, though the most useful instructions for Air are [from untoldentertainment.com](http://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/2011/11/23/flash-to-ios-a-step-by-step-tutorial-part-1/).