# Common IDE to develop mobile applications and deploy it to iphone, Android, Blackberry etc

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Technology to write iPhone, BlackBerry and Android phone at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821085/technology-to-write-iphone-blackberry-and-android-phone-at-the-same-time)

Is there any common IDE to develop single code base and deploy it to Android, iPhone,  Symbian OS, Brew, Windows Mobile or Palm OS and blackberry handsets?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [AirplaySDK](http://www.airplaysdk.com/), it allows you to develop a mobile application against their framework and then compile it as an ARM binary and deploy it to most mobile platforms (including some game consoles).

It has some disadvantages, but if portability is your main goal, it's a good option, and the performance is very good because it runs as native ARM.

EDIT: Some OpenSource alternatives (that I haven't tested) are:

 - [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

 - [Rhomobile](http://rhomobile.com/)

 - [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

Al of them are more Web oriented, and compile to native mobile applications.

EDIT: They wrap a native client around your web application, it's a very different approach to AirPlaySDK that compiles to native code.

Hope it helps.

Regards!

Comment: Is there any open source technology?

Comment: Edited to add OpenSource alternatives to AirPlaySDK

Comment: @acnu:But i dont think apple will accept your app if you use any outside SDK/IDE/frameworks other then their own..

Comment: @Alpha There are already many apps in the AppStore using all mentioned technologies. The problem raises when you use a private API.

Answer (score 1):

[Qt :)](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) is still the rockstart. You do not have to go that far.  If you can hack it, there is a trick with one punch!! knock all out:

> IOS/Android/Symbian/Meego/Blackberry/WebOS HP/Windows Mobile too.

- A good start for Android can be: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suPeZ7XC1xk
  http://sourceforge.net/projects/necessitas/files/
- for iOS there are several branches (you'll have to compile them yourself) - here is blog about one of them http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/03/11/new-proof-of-concept-uikit-based-lighthouse-platform/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.metismo.com/ 
Check this.It allows you to develop mobile applications regardless of the target system.

Answer (score 0):

Each platform has its nuances and "perfect" implementation will be limited to the least common denominator between all platforms. Low-level and hardware-specific needs are best addressed natively. However web-based frameworks like Sencha Touch or jqTouch do a good job if you merely want users to submit/receive content.

Sencha Touch is built for iOS and Android and the 1.1 version of the framework now supports BlackBerry 6. These apps are written in Javascript and can be published as regular mobile websites (*in webkit browsers) or wrapped in PhoneGap as pseudo-"native" apps. In the iOS case, this buys you the option of putting the app on the App Store.

Appcelerator's Titanium is another Javascript-based solution cross-compiled into the native language of your choice.

Another option to consider is Adobe flash/flex/air. You can write once and publish to many platforms, web, or the device of your choice.

Just remember that all of these cross-compiler and multi-platform solutions come at a cost. You get more platforms for the price of developing once (plus learning the framework and adapting for the "nuances" of each target), but your app may not seem as "polished" or have access to as many slick features native apps enjoy. Something to think about.

best Of luck in your Mobile endeavorS.