# Is there any framework that works on Android and iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, ios, cross-platform, smartphone

I want to develop and deploy application on iPhone and Android.

However there is a problem, as far as I know iPhone is using XCode and Objective-C, plus I can't even develop iPhone applications on Windows/Linux. Android is using Java.

So basically I will need to develop two different products.

My question is - is there some kind of framework I can use to build one application which runs on iPhone and Android or is making two separate applications my only option?

As far as I can see most of these 'frameworks' are working like browsers. You see website using WebKit on Android/iOS the same anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5393844/716216 and numerous other questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Technology to write iPhone, BlackBerry and Android phone at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821085/technology-to-write-iphone-blackberry-and-android-phone-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [**PhoneGap**](http://phonegap.com/) - uses HTML5 & JavaScript/jQuery Mobile.
- [**Rhodes**](http://www.rhomobile.com/) - uses Ruby & JavaScript/jQuery Mobile
- [**Titanium**](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/)
- [**MoSync**](http://www.mosync.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The [NSBasic](http://www.nsbasic.com/app/) IDE will translate their variant of Basic code into cross-platform Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap is very popular for it. it can create cross platform mobile applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use phonegap or you can just make a website