# Objective-C and then what? Android, Windows 7, Blackberry

Tags: android, objective-c, compiler-construction, mobile-phones, mobile-application

Question: what should one focus on when there is a strong need to develop Apps for multiple platforms? I spend all this time focusing on Obj-C, but that get's me no where with Android, Windows 7 or Blackberry.

At it stands, Objective-C isn't even the language that the iPhone ends up using. Obj-C is compiled for the iPhone. So there must be a way to write the Apps in a more global language and then have it compiled for the iPhone, Android and Blackberry...

Recommendations?

Comment: Are you trying to develop a particular app or just talking about building a skillset in general?

Comment: I'd like to be able to utilize the iPhone, Android and Blackberry platforms FULLLY without having to employ a different language and development platform for each.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a multiplatform framework for developing iPhone / Android applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953/is-there-a-multiplatform-framework-for-developing-iphone-android-applications)

Comment: See also [What work has been done on cross-platform mobile development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988/what-work-has-been-done-on-cross-platform-mobile-development) and [Technology to write iPhone, BlackBerry and Android phone at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821085/technology-to-write-iphone-blackberry-and-android-phone-at-the-same-time)

Comment: See http://www.apportable.com/ to use Objective-C for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Focus on flexibility. There is no "holy grail" language that is perfect for everything, so having the ability to adapt and learn as needed is important.

Comment: There's no Holy Grail, but as it stands, Objective-C isn't the language that the iPhone uses anyway. It still needs to be compiled for the iPhone.

Comment: Objective-C is the language the iPhone uses natively in any meaningful sense. All high level native libraries are written in and talk to each other according to the semantics and fundaments of Objective-C, and make use of the Objective-C runtime. If you're discounting anything that needs to be compiled then all devices you mention have exactly one language: ARM assembly.

Comment: I understand that the frameworks have been written in Obj-C, but I know I'm not the only person on the planet that finds the separation irritating. iPhone, Android, Blackberry, Win. Mobile, etc... all different. It's ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look at MonoTouch/[Mono For Android](http://mono-android.net/) or [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/) if you want to write once and run on multiple mobile platforms.