# Is jQuery Mobile ready for production use?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've been meaning to use jQuery Mobile for a client project that is to go live in about 2 months (in the end of April) but I can't seem to find any roadmap for jQuery Mobile.

It is now in [Alpha 3](http://jquerymobile.com/2011/02/jquery-mobile-alpha-3-released/) stage. There were only one month between [Alpha 1](http://jquerymobile.com/2010/10/jquery-mobile-alpha-1-released/) and [Alpha 2](http://jquerymobile.com/2010/11/jquery-mobile-alpha-2-released/) but about two and a half months between [Alpha 2](http://jquerymobile.com/2010/11/jquery-mobile-alpha-2-released/) and [Alpha 3](http://jquerymobile.com/2011/02/jquery-mobile-alpha-3-released/).

According to the [Bug Tracker](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues), jQuery Mobile has 231 open issues where many of them are critical or high or even 2 with status Blocker.

I really wan't to use this framework because of it's ambition to reach so many clients and my feelings for jQuery in general :) But is it wise at this point in time?

**Update 2011-03-04**

According to http://jquerymobile.com/2011/02/jquery-mobile-alpha-3-released/: "Right now we’re planning on releasing the first beta within the month before moving on to our 1.0 release."

According to [sidneyallen](http://twitter.com/#!/sidneyallen): "#jquery mobile Beta ETA is mid to late April. Overheard at Bay Area Mobile meetup."

**Update 2011-03-23**

[According to jQuery Mobile's official Twitter account](http://twitter.com/#!/jquerymobile/status/50322801214767104), jQuery Mobile Alpha 4 should be released within a week and beta should be out by [San Francisco jQuery conference](http://events.jquery.org/2011/sf-bay-area/) which is held April 16-17.

**Update 2011-04-30**

Yes, jQM Alpha 4 was indeed [released a week after](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/03/31/jquery-mobile-alpha-4-released/) my last update with lots of improvements. The beta was at this point in time still planned to be released by mid-April in time for the jQuery conference.

April 7th, the team release [jQM Alpha 4.1](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/04/07/jquery-alpha-4-1-maintenance-release/) which was a maintenance release. They now announced that they might not make the schedule for the beta release.

April 16th, it is now much easier to use the [latest version (nightly builds)](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/04/16/nightly-and-up-to-date-builds/) in your development project.

April 21st, looks like [the team is hunting down some bugs](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/04/21/jquery-mobile-team-meeting-april-21-2010/).

**Update 2011-05-23**

In their [most recent blog post](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/05/20/jquery-mobile-team-update-%E2%80%93-week-of-may-16th/) the jQuery team announced that beta is soon to be released. The new date is end of May / early June. Major refactoring of navigation and better platform support are the big things they want to get ready before a beta release.

**Update 2011-06-22**

The long awaited [beta 1 release is finally here](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/06/20/jquery-mobile-beta-1-released/). It was released two days ago and includes support for more platforms including Blackberry 5 and Opera Mini. Since our team hadn't updated jQM since Alpha 4.1 which was released April 7th there were a lot of improvements and bugfixes. The experience was definitely better regarding floating headers, transitions between pages and navigation in general. We did not encounter any breaking changes that affected our code. Well there were some but they had to do with updating jQuery core from 1.5.1 to 1.6.1.

A second beta should be out the door within a month and 1.0 should be released late this summer.

Now I really think jQuery Mobile is production ready. I really can't see any other alternatives with such a broad device/desktop reach.

Comment: Re broad device reach - did you look at Sencha Touch?

Comment: @Art I did a quick review when my project started and I didn't liked the fact that it was commercial, didn't aim for really broad reach, tries to mimic native apps or the way you developed using it. And last but not least, the fact that John Resig wasn't involved in building it :)

Comment: I have been programming for 30 years and as of this date I can state conclusively that if you want to build a full featured interactive transaction system with jquery mobile you will spend most of your time building workarounds for strange and unpredictable behavior.  That being said there doesn't seem to be any alternative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**the final update**

jQuery Mobile Framework has gone a long way. It's obviously ready for production environments. Most notably, performance and size issues have been resolved.

Still not a good choice if you only want to get the 'looks' and ignore what framework does. Then it's just a waste of bandwidth, because you can get all the shiny buttons from just CSS, without 100k of JS framework code

**yet another update**

JQMbeta2 is great. I suppose you can safely use it and later update to the full 1.0 with minor changes in your code.

**update**

In my humble opinion you can already try to use JQMalpha4.1 for production (I do) but beta release will differ for sure. (I'll have to make some changes in my code)

Beta release will surely be ready to use for production. No doubt. :)

---

You can use it "as is" as long as you can provide devices for testing your app, because there are a lot of issues you might need to work around. But as long as it's tested and working - you have a good app.

The problem with production is that jQuery Mobile might still change the api and names and how stuff work so if you create an app now, it might not work with future releases.

Therefore this depends on your app a lot. If you are planning on using JQM for enhancing semantic HTML and not write lots of JS and CSS hacks, then you can risk starting the project with alpha3 IMHO.

Remember to get the latest version from repository and test if newer versions still work with your code from time to time. It's the bugfixes that you need the most.

Answer (score 5):

In developing a client site with it, the answer is a solid "maybe". It does a lot of things right, and Alpha 3 is a huge improvement, but there are definitely bugs and missing features that make it difficult to work with and make some interactions currently impossible.

It's a great project, and has a ton of potential, but I'd carefully judge your client's needs. If the current limitations are not show-stoppers, it's tons of fun to use and greatly accelerates mobile development.

Comment: One example that comes to mind is support for "scroll views", which is still experimental at this point: http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/ It works, but not great. Equally frustrating is that sometimes it eats standard jQuery events. As naugtur posted - it's JS/CSS hacks that are the least reliable, and if you find yourself hacking to get around the framework, you'll probably be in a really bad place.

Comment: I don't like the performance on Android devices. Sometimes apps appear to be extremely choppy and sometimes the layouts crash. Nav bars disappear and the elements show up in a messy way... I can't tell when and why exactly that happens but it does happen after a while clicking / taping around. (Version: Alpha 4.1)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you have a look at the list of [Blockers](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues?labels=6%20-%20Blocker&sort=created&direction=desc&state=open&page=1) and [Critical](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues?labels=5%20-%20Critical&sort=created&direction=desc&state=open&page=1) on the jQuery Mobile issue tracking system.

Go through those and see whether any of them are possible show stoppers for you.

UPD: I am personally finding that it is not acceptable for the stuff I am working on. We need to use sub-page navigation via hash, i.e. #controller/action/id and there's nothing like that in jQuery mobile. So we had to switch to Sencha Touch, which does brilliant job at that.

Comment: Agree! There are many. One need to look at the and decide if they have an impact on the requirements of the current project.

Comment: It's pretty close i agree, unless you want to build in a few hacks, and be prepared to change them in future release, then you can probably productionize. personally, i would learn now, and move to prod when it's stable

Comment: UPDATE: Actually I would say it's not production ready for what I need it to do - namely working navigation in # urls - that is vital  for any kind of sane single page web app with multiple 'sub-pages' and proper separation of concerns via mvc pattern

Answer (score 1):

Jquery Mobile the Beta version released last week(June 11) is closest one. If you are not concerned about licensing. Sproutcore and SenchaTouch are other two ones that I like

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the beta 1 took 3 more months than estimate, not the "1 more month", I wouldn't be optimistic about the release schedule.  Since we don't know how many betas are actually planned by the team, there's no way to know when it will be ready.  But at the rate they are going, it might be unrealistic to assume anytime in 2011 it will be 1.0 ready.

Comment: the blog looks promising: weekly updates with significant progress

Comment: Steve, I agree, things are changing and people need to keep in mind that my answer is extremely time sensitive and might not even apply anymore.