# JQM vs GWT mobile vs Sencha

Tags: jquery, gwt, frameworks, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch

After going through so many documents and online content like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066167/sencha-touch-or-jquery-mobile
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093691/sencha-touch-vs-jqtouch-vs-gwt-mobile-vs-xui-vs-jquery-mobile-vs
http://www.quora.com/Were-deciding-between-jQuery-Mobile-currently-in-alpha-and-Sencha-Touch-What-are-the-pros-and-cons-for-each
http://interfacethis.com/2011/adventures-in-html5-part-one/
```

and many more,
I thought of posting this questions since I am not able to choose a  proper frame work for my mobile web app. 
I already have a native app running on android but I developing native apps for each and every platform would be expensive and consumes more time. I am looking for proper framework which should work seamlessly on android iPhone and BB platforms and also on tablets and mobile phones and ipad.

In the native android app I have successfully and implemented XMPP chat , file transfers using FTP.

Presently I have a web services written using SOAP and XML which transits data from android to the database at the server. I am wondering how to implement this features if I am using either sencha or jQuery mobile?

Kindly help me and help me to choose the right frame work from which I can implement this core features in my app

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but I advise moving from SOAP to REST, especially for mobiles.

Comment: @rickyduck: We were using REST itself but our development team skill sets are more favorable for SOAP, so we switched to SOAP.

Comment: ok.. I still think maybe they should take the time to learn it. It's not too difficult, if they can develop SOAP clients, REST should be fairly easy for them. Anyways, what do you want this mobile web app to do? It may help the question get answered more appropriately.

Comment: @rickyduck:my app handles more dynamic data, I am not looking for offline app, my app works only when der is a connection. I am worried about FTP file transfers and also XMPP real time chat,b'coz in the android native app we can use Core Java but when it comes to mobile web app frame work its more of HTML and Javascript.

Comment: Hmm, i'll post this as my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For larger scale apps I would recommend using Sencha Mobile, however it will be a learning curve if it hasn't been used before. jQuery mobile will still be able to support anything you want though, and I have no experience with GWT - however I have heard it is slow to develop larg scale applications on this framework.

I would recommend Sencha, however I wouldn't NOT recommend jQuery mobile. Build two small scale apps in all 3 frameworks, and see which ones you feel comfortable with, are most efficient with and works best. A couple of hours testing development with a definite answer is better than a couple of hours researching each frameworks, only to finish with still no definite answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about trying to eliminate the choices one by one? Pick one of the framework from the list and try to answer this question:

> Is there anything in this framework that will make it unsuitable for
>   my application?

Document your answer for each framework so you know why your rejected a particular option. Once you have done the above exercise, hopefully, you will have only one, two or ever zero frameworks left for consideration.

You can use a list of must-haves to make your elimination process easy, for example:

1. Should support iPhone, iPad, BB and Android
2. Primary language should be Javascript (or Java etc.)
3. Must be free/open source
4. Must have active community of users
5. Must have a paid support option
6. Must have a number of successful reference applications demonstrating the capability and cross-platform nature.
7. etc.

Comment: Thanks Tahir this activity would actually help me to decide, I shell do this and answer here so that it will be helpful for others

Answer (score 1):

I do not have experience on GWT mobile, but for JQM and sencha I can say that ST is based on ExtJS 4 and brings the MVC pattern to the table with lots of emphasis on performance and security. Opting for Sencha Touch could be a good decision

But if you are looking for simple web based and very less time to market applications, jQuery Mobile could be a good decision because of its simplicity and its very Web-centric approach to development.

Comment: Self-promotional, without disclosure.