# Mobile HTML5 frameworks - Jquery mobile

Tags: html, frameworks, mobile, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

Just wanted to know if Jquery mobile is stable enough to use for a live production enterprise mobile application.

There are many HTML5 frameworks out there, since our team has been using JQuery for quite some time we would prefer to use the Jquery mobile framework.

Its is still in Alpha stage but have read a lot of good reviews for the same, we also plan to build custom native apps for the Iphone, Android and Blackberry but would like to have an app that runs on all devices.

Regards,
Sheldon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Starbucks seems to think it's stable enough to work with](https://www.starbucks.com/account/create/register/mobile). [Disney](http://m.disneyparksportraits.com/), [Audi](http://www.jqmgallery.com/2011/04/27/audi-a7-bold-design/), [the BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/touch/), and [Barack Obama](http://www.barackobama.com/m/) too.

Comment: thanks for the live examples, @Phill Pafford and yes I still have time to get to production so I am definitely going to build a version of my app with JQM and keep updating it as new versions are released.

Answer (score 5):

It's good, but I'm not sure if it's good enough for a live production application.

I'm running a small website on it for a school project I'm doing and there's quite a lot of annoying bugs. Footers like to disappear at the most unexpected moments, I get a lot of 'jumpiness' where the page just jumps around and shows a black or white background-color, of which I don't know where it comes from. It's also fairly slow on my host, but that might just be because of the host and not because of the framework, however it's something you should probably test before going live with it.

That being said, the framework is easy to work with and if your team is good enough you might be able to hack your way through some of the bugs; it's easy to create a website with it which does look good, if you take the unexpected bugginess into account. Then again, I guess these little bugs are to be expected with an alpha release.

I personally wouldn't recommend it for a live production site, but it might be a personal thing and you should probably try it out for yourself. As far as other recommendations go, I have heard good things about [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/), but I haven't tried it myself.

EDIT: Some more information/comparisons [here](http://interfacethis.com/2011/adventures-in-html5-part-one/).

EDIT2: As far as a roadmap goes, they said they would release it when 1.0 hits. However, their release plan seems to be subject to change. Also check out this question: [Is jQuery Mobile ready for production use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071369/is-jquery-mobile-ready-for-production-use)

Answer (score 1):

Its good enough now to go live.
Its in 1.01 version now and quite stable

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good idea to hold off IMHO, it's alpha, there are lots of 'issues':

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues

Comment: @Raoul @cabaret thanks for the answers, I would definitely try it out on a demo project here to get some hands on experience with the framework. Also is there any kind of roadmap as to where the framework is heading I could not find one on the main site.

Comment: They said they would release a roadmap when 1.0 hits; however they also announced beta for april and we're almost june now so yeah.. Guess you'll have to wait a bit for it :( Updated my answer.

Comment: You're going to find ticket issues in any open source project.

Comment: @ceejayoz well obviously. However some are actually out of Alpha. Suggesting using an Alpha framework in production isn't wise IMHO, there is too much which could be subject to change. But thanks for over simplifying the problem, and missing the point.

Comment: Some are out of Alpha, sure, but in my experience many of them are less stable than jQuery Mobile already is. "Alpha", "Beta", etc. are all just labels, meaningless on their own. The framework should be evaluated on its merits, not the fact that it has a Github issue tracker.

Comment: @ceejayoz  @Raoul @cabaret   I managed to get something up and running   http://tastykhana.in/m/ the great part is the simplicity of the framework

Answer (score 0):

I agree, jQM is still in alpha which means there are still enough bug/problems/features that are not up to par yet. But the jQM team is very quick to respond to Q&A's and is pushing for the first Beta release soon. IMHO (if time is not an option) I would start with jQM alpha if you think you're going to (in the end) use jQM for the final version of your webapp. I think getting the basic design and functionality can be done with the current release and just make the necessary updates for specific functionality when available. You can always keep track of the current (I think it's updated weekly) Status of what is being worked on/fixed/etc.. on the Blog: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/

I know there are other Mobile Frameworks out there but the scope of jQM on how many devices it should run on swayed me on selecting jQM as my framework