# Mobile App frameworks?

Tags: mobile, mobile-website

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing Mobile Web HTML5 Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063117/choosing-mobile-web-html5-framework)

What is the best framework for developing mobile web apps ( HTML5, Css and Jquery )  for iPhone and other smartphones

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063117/choosing-mobile-web-html5-framework

Answer (score 0):

You cant go wrong with the ones you mentioned.  However I like to use .NET in combination with what you mentioned, (i havent worked with HTML 5 yet) and use the the capabilities/browser files to get more in depth functionality to target more specific browsers if needed.