# Mobile framework library size, how important is it?

Tags: mobile, frameworks, size

Trying to decide which way to go for a mobile framework and some say stay away from Sencha Touch because the size of the library (~374kb) or DHTMLX Touch (~170kb).

Is it that important?  If so what size is the cutoff point where it is a concern?

It is hard to sell DHTMLX Touch or Sencha Touch when you are comparing them to jQuery Mobile which is so small.

Comment: If the mobile system has enough system memory and/or storage is 204kb really going to make a difference?  Which of the frameworks has the require functionality you require?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery mobile requires two js file

- jquery.min.js - 93kb
- jquery.mobile.min.js - 83kb

which gives 176kb - so there is no big advantage vs above libs (actually it is bigger than dhtmlx touch).

The information about size of js library can be confusing, on jquery's site they say's only about gzipped size (24kb) but do not mention full size, nor the size of other required files, which gives false impression of very small size.

P.S. And I'm agree with the above comment - first criteria of library choosing must be the required functionality, not the library's size

Answer (score 1):

I have personally used Sencha Touch but not version 2, used jQuery Mobile and DHTMLX Touch.

I have a preference of DHTMLX Touch because it felt easier for me to learn, it had a superior performance and the quality of the controls were the best among all the frameworks I have tested.

With today mobile phones storage capability, and the performance, I don't think few KBytes would matter anymore. Size is important but it is not something that will make me decide on a framework to choose. Unless both frameworks are neck to neck and only size is the difference.

Please have a read on this discussion too: [Choosing Mobile Web HTML5 Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063117/choosing-mobile-web-html5-framework)