# Android Cross-Platforming

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform

I want to know more about Cross-Platform. I'm currently working on my thesis and decided to make an `Android Application` but not all target users uses `Android device`. So, We've come up with an idea to Cross-Platform the android application.

I have read the same topic but it didn't get to me too well. [iOS / Android cross platform development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171128/ios-android-cross-platform-development). I want to know if there is another way than using the frameworks discussed in the link.

**I want know what is the best/shortest way to cross platform a Android Application?**

Comment: look at phonegap to get a sense of what is/is not possible on both platforms.  The rest of the sdks are a can of worms.

Comment: Generally with phone gap you might end up having to do a custom plugin for each platform you support. It does not have everything out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Cross Platform tools are in my opinion not a good idea at all.  Android is Java, and iOS is Objective C.  Android can use NDK to use a C/C++ library so theoretically if you did most of your code in C/C+ it could be used on both sides.  I think two natives is more in order.  Study NDK to see what could run on both devices.  Lets say you built your app as a C++ Library except for UI interactions. Then in theory the library should work on both sides.  C/C++ a lot easier on iOS than android however.

Also it really depends on the dependencies your app will have.  Lets say you want to use a library but its only available in Java or C++ how does this effect your decision.

You might also consider designing your app so that it just captures data on the devices and the actual processing of the data takes place in a web service.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is use Mobile Web HTML5 Framework like [Phonegapp](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html), [Sencha touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) and more.

Although web technologies don’t perform as well as native, but it is a useful thing that you can try.

See [Choosing Mobile Web HTML5 Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063117/choosing-mobile-web-html5-framework) and http://operationproject.com/2011/adventures-in-html5-part-one/

Answer (score 0):

Android application are apk files that are basically zip file that contains dex/odex files and all other resources that you may wish to add.But I think you can use any coding language to develop as long as you have IDE that converts your code to apk and dex .And most important of all your programming language must support corresponding api or must have something similar to cross compile.The reason Google used Java for Android was they felt it is convenient  to do it(read it during case Google v/s Oracle)

Personally I feel cross-platform is good since it increases the developers base and understanding of the System (here Android).And  I think the same analogy would go with other Systems as well.