# What is an enterprise centric application

Tags: web-applications, architecture, design-patterns

I was going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063117/choosing-mobile-web-html5-framework) thread

I do'nt really understand What an enterprise centric application means.

What is its characteristics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Large corporations often take things into account which small, individual, developers do not.

One of the biggest factors is often support.  In particular, can they buy guaranteed support contracts so that they (in theory) can spend less time tinkering with the product and just submit a ticket if they run into a problem.

A related factor is control over feature requests.  For example, if the enterprise deems some undeveloped feature to be critical to their application they will often want the flexibility to negotiate a contract of the form "we will pay you X dollars if you give us feature Y by date Z".

Finally, enterprise corporations are often looking for longevity.  They do not want to invest time and training into a platform that will die off in a year or two.

For this reason, traditional enterprise corporations will often go with an older, slower technology that is more established and has the backing of a large company or organization.