# CrossPaltform Mobile Application

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, cordova, mobile-website

I want to do the following:

1- mobile friendly Portal - accessed through different Mobile Phones.

2- A mobile Applications that does the same functionality of the portal to different Platforms:
 iOS(iPhone,iPad), BlackberryOS(Blackberry mobiles and Playbooks),Android OS (Android mobiles and Tabs), WindowsOS, Symbian OS (Smartphones).

I am mainly a web Developer and an iOS programmer using Objective-C, and I have resources that can develop on android, blackberry and other platforms using native languages.

the Application mainly present data from internal database and deals with different types of web services, and write data to the file system of the device itself.

what is the best practice for the mobile applications, do each one alone with its native language, or using HTML,CSS,JS and produce them to all platforms using PhoneGap or something else???

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What work has been done on cross-platform mobile development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988/what-work-has-been-done-on-cross-platform-mobile-development)

Answer (score 1):

Also check this thread : [best cross-mobile framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086863/best-cross-mobile-javascript-framework-iphone-android/6723422)

With a javascript solution, your app will be available on stores but also directly on the web !