# One mobile app runs in all platforms. Is that Possible?

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, java-me, mobile-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What work has been done on cross-platform mobile development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51988/what-work-has-been-done-on-cross-platform-mobile-development)

Is there any mobile application development framework available by which I can develop a app that will run in all all platforms like iphone,Android,Blacberry.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look to PhoneGap http://www.phonegap.com/ or Appcelerator Titanuim http://www.appcelerator.com/.

Comment: Ohh ! Phonegap seems amazing .. I must have to learn this otherwise my job would be in danger :)

Answer (score 2):

As Feanor said, web application is the only way to go if you are targetting all applications with one build. You can use many javascript libraries optimized for the mobile. Such as [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com), [JQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/) and [Wink Toolkit](http://www.winktoolkit.org/). You can use PhoneGap to wrap these web apps so you can sell on them on the respective device appstore.

Titanium does try to provide cross platform developement to some extent but if you application is a bit more than a simple app it wont be easy as even they has different api's for different platforms. The only difference is you can use javascript to develop for all the platforms in Titanium.

The main difficulty in doing a cross platform app is that, the api's and ui philisophy are different for each platform. The langauge in which development is done is not the only difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make a Cross-Compilable application. The closest you are getting are something like Phonegap, which uses HTML5 and CC3 as a webapp.

The problem with those applications is the lack of native opportunities and you are loosing  performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can build HTML5 web apps for iphone,android and blackberry(http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/03/use-html5-in-your-blackberry-web-content/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to notme's suggestion consider marmalade http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/ the clever part of marmalade is that it produces a single binary that will run on all platforms.

Be aware that there are always compromises when you use such frameworks. Many are explicit but some are hidden - like you might have trouble attracting developers to work on them.